# grunt serve VS opening index.html in browser

Tags: angularjs, cordova, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm using Yeoman and the angular-fullstack generator to bootstrap an angular app. When I do `grunt serve` or `grunt serve:dist` everything works as expected.

Now the question is, when I open the index.html file directly in the browser, isn't it supposed to work equally?

So I have a hard time understanding whats tasks grunt is executing here to make it work. Or maybe I am missing something else.

The console tells me:

```
GET file:///app/8d57a97f.app.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
GET file:///app/47ab0f3e.vendor.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
GET file:///app/01b9b8a8.app.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

The generated index.html looks something like this:

```
<!doctype html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <base href="/">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/8d57a97f.app.css"/>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp"> 
    <!-- some functionality... -->  
    <script src="app/47ab0f3e.vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="app/01b9b8a8.app.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

*The reason why I do this:*

I try to run the angular app with phonegap on an android device. When I load it to the android mobile, the screen remains blank. So I opened it in the browser and got the same result.

So this is my first attempt to solve this issue.

Comment: You can't make AJAX calls to a file. Only to a HTTP server. So an angular application served from the file system won't work as soon as it makes any AJAX call. That said, the error you have there just show that files don't exist. The grunt server probably serves files from multiple directories.

Comment: You are right, now the GET makes sense. But I dont understand why the script tag wouldn't check here for a local resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `<base href="/">` in the header.

Explanation can be found here ([Loading local file in browser referenced css or js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279531/loading-local-file-in-browser-referenced-css-or-js)).