# phonegap app with angular-fullstack-generator

Tags: cordova, gruntjs, angular-fullstack

The task is to run an app, created with the [angular-fullstack-generator](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) by [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), with [phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html).

For anybody interested, these are the most promising tutorials I found for this:

- [Getting Started with Mobile App Development with PhoneGap + Yeoman + AngularJS + Ionic](http://frontendmatters.com/getting-started-mobile-app-development-phonegap-yeoman-angularjs-ionic/)
- [Quick Start Guide to PhoneGap+AngularJS](http://devgirl.org/2013/06/10/quick-start-guide-phonegap-and-angularjs/) by Holly Schinsky. (the UI parts work, but the functionality doesn't - with the basic setup)
- [Building PhoneGap Apps with AngularJS](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-phonegap) by Brian Ford. (seems like the codebase changed at some points, so i really didnt get it to work)

So the first tutorial led me to a working solution with the [angular-generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) by the yeoman team. But now with the angular-fullstack-generator I run into the following issue. The console tells me:

```
Failed to load resource file:///app/45eec174.app.css
Failed to load resource file:///app/f9250ffb.vendor.js
Failed to load resource file:///app/90992454.app.js
Failed to load resource file://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
```

So my suspect so far is the `<base href="/">` tag generated in the head of the `index.html`. Similar to this [SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279531/loading-local-file-in-browser-referenced-css-or-js). Simply removing it is no option.

Now my understanding of grunt is limited, but why does it work the given way with `grunt serve`?

And how would I fix this to get it to work in with phonegap?

Comment: You don't give a lot of information to go on, but if I had to make an educated guess, I would say that your index.html is in the wrong location. Where is it located relatively to your app folder?

Comment: its in the same folder like app

Answer (score 2):

I am in the same mission. But yet to make it work. However, as a first step, I managed to run the UI as a standalone applicaiton.

Your guess is correct,

This base tag is used by angular throughout the application while loading templates. At the same time, including base tag will not find the resources included in index.html. I did the following

1. Removed base tag from index.html
2. In angular config did the following

   $locationProvider.html5Mode({
     enabled: true,
     requireBase: false
   });

step#2, helps the angular to work in html5mode without requiring base tag.

3. Change all backend service calls in the form http://backendurl.com:port/api/service
4. do not serve socket-io-client from server
5. install socket-io-client as a bower component in client side
6. connect socket-io-client with backend url
7. build fullstack for dist (grunt build:dist)
8. create a symbolic link for \dist\public to cordovaapppath\www
9. build cordova app (cordova build android)

you are done. I have successfully managed to create my application using phonegap. I have created a github project extending from Angular fullstack.  https://github.com/kannach/AFSPhonegap

please try and contribute.

Comment: thank you so much, exactly what i needed!!
how did you fix the urls for the api-calls? to which reference?
same problem with all assets, since to refere img's, a simple ""assets/images/image.png" is not working anymore...
("./" prefix is not working)

Comment: I have created a constant service, in which i could configure the backend url. In all the files that has $http.get, injected this constant service and prefixed with the api. something like "constant.backenturl + /api/action".

Comment: that's exactely what I'm trying to do as well :) I'm just not figuring out, what root cordova is refering, when giving paths (e.g. form img src)... do you know in which directory cordova is ltaking as "root" after its "file:///" ? in other word, how can I specify where it should look for? (when loading the .js files, it's root is "android_asset/www/....",although there is no such folder). Differentiating whether it's running on cordova or not and taking the respective baseUrl would solve the problem. Are you doing it that way? if yes, how?

thanks for you help!

Comment: I managed to get it working, but I'm not satisfied, since it's quite "ugly":

API-Calls:
Somehow api-calls on localhost:9000/api don't work in cordova, entering the local ip instead is working...

Assets:
As baseUrl I inserted "android_asset....<path to assets>"

do you have any idea how this is done "properly" without that hack?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I didnt get time to check lately. I have just setup a github project, I will integrate my changes there. perhaps, i can get it working by end of this week.

Comment: I have managed to run the phonegap app. I created a github project with my changes. please have a look https://github.com/kannach/AFSPhonegap. I will edit my answer soon.

Comment: Thanks Chandru for providing a clear solution.
I already managed to get it run as well, though I'm not creating a symbolic link, just copying the contents of "dist/public/" into cordova/www. this does the trick as well.

Comment: Hi, I am also in the same mission, but in my case its giving me `Cannot read property '1' of null` this error. this is at here `<div ui-view=""></div>` if i remove this div, error goes but view are not loading. any suggestions?

Comment: Do you still have your base tag in index.html?

Answer (score 0):

For now, after do all @Chandru guide, you must do one more thing if you use Generator Angular Fullstack version after version [4.0.0 Beta 2 Webpack support](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/releases/tag/4.0.0-beta.2):

In webpack.make.js change the line:

```
publicPath: BUILD || DEV || E2E ? '/' : `http://localhost:${8080}/`,
```

to

```
publicPath: BUILD || DEV || E2E ? '' : `http://localhost:${8080}/`,
```